# Site showing white background behind status bar on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile

Im having trouble with the status bar color on my website for iOS device. The background color seems to be ignored and there is a white bar behind the status bar on my ios device. I’ve tried setting up theme-color and apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style meta tags with HSL color tags but they don’t seem to do anything. When I minimize the page and open another tab and come back to it, sometimes the background behind the status bar becomes the correct color and works like I would like it to.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I can fix this?
[bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWJu2.png)
[good example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V58Zc.png)

Code on website.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the `background-color` property to the `html` element.
when the style was only applied to the body the area behind the status bar and under the navigation bar would be white and draggable